# Rails button on click call method

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I am still learning Ruby on Rails and was trying to do call a custom method `check_bike_in` in that controller and passing it the values from the check box and text area when I click the button.

I am using the helper_method to call `check_bike_in`, but I am not sure how to call it when the button is clicked or how to pass the variables to the controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<table class="checked_out">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Bike</th>
    <th>Checkout time</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @checkouts.each do |checkout| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="user"><%= checkout.user_id %></td>
        <td class="bike_number"><%= checkout.bike_id %></td>
        <td><button onclick="$('#<%= checkout.id %>').toggle()">Check Bike In</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="display: none" id = "<%= checkout.id %>">
        <td class="needs_reapir_checkbox"><input type="checkbox"> Needs Repair</td>
        <td class="repair_textbox"><textarea rows="1" cols="50"></textarea></td>
        <td><button onclick="">Check In</button></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method is a POST or GET?, If your method is POST you need a submit buttom inside a form to send the data otherwise you need a link with the parameters:

Example:

For POST method

```
<td><%= button_to 'Check Bike In', action: :check_bike_in, id: checkout.id %></td>
```

For GET method

```
<td><%= link_to 'Check Bike In', action: :check_bike_in, id: checkcout.id %></td>
```

Comment: I am trying to do a POST and if I pass i nthe checkout.id then will that pass in the textarea and check box inside that tag? I am just afraid rails params would stop that from being passed in. (usign raisl 4. Sorry new to trying to not use a form_for to do things in rails.